# AWS Endpoint Management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 4 endpoints which have been created with buckets to store images for various scans of pdf documents, images and certain control file metadata related to the stored documents. The endpoints mapped to geographical locations over different locations. I am artificially managing the storage of documents by implementing a custom solution for where these documents can be stored. I want to evenly distribute them across these 4 centers. I have 4 endpoints like this

```java
                    const siteOneEndPt = new AWS.Endpoint('site.one.com');
                    const siteOneS3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: siteOneEndPt});

                    const siteTwoEndPt = new AWS.Endpoint('site.two.com');
                    const siteTwoS3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: siteTwoEndPt});

                    const siteThreeEndPt = new AWS.Endpoint('site.three.com');
                    const siteThreeS3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: siteThreeEndPt});

                    const siteFourEndPt = new AWS.Endpoint('site.four.com');
                    const siteFourS3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: siteFourEndPt});
```

Is there a way to manage these endpoints using some AWS Configuration in the SDK where I can specify these endpoints and have the API manage them? I am currently using a custom round robin solution I wrote to cycle from one endpoint to the other but wondering whether the SDK provides a better way. I'd appreciate if someone knows and whether they can point me to how the management could be achieved. The use of EndPoint has been deprecated, how can I connect to the server using the S3Client. How do I pass the parameters to the S3Client to connect to the siteOne for example?

Comment: It looks like you're building a Content Delivery Network (CDN). Is it so?. AWS has CloudFront for that. See details https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront.  CF need a single bucket and will deliver S3 Obejcts via 450+ globally dispersed Points of Presence

Comment: No,  I need to have docs about 3,000 of them a month to s3, process them and delete them. I have 4 independent sites available to sending these documents, but I was wondering if there was a way to have AWS manage those in say similar to what a load balancer would do